# how to cast an indirect pointer in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, casting

I am trying to do some work on my keychain and am following this tutorial [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html)
Unfortunately I am getting the following error where it talks about searching the keychain

```
Cast of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'CFTypeRef *' (aka 'const void **') is disallowed with ARC
```

This is what the code looks like

```
 OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,(CFTypeRef *)&result);
```

Any help providing the correct code on how to cast indirect pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cast before you pass.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use void * instead:

```
 OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary,(void *)&result);
```